# storyboard not autoresizing

Tags: swift, storyboard

On my phone the view seems to be zoomed in (to large for the screen)
Screenshot from iphone 5s

[image]

Compared to when Im building it in xcode:
[image]

Comment: You don't have your constraints setup correctly in auto-layout.

Comment: how do i set them up?  where is this configuration at?

Comment: @owengerig it's a long journey you can google it for dozens of tutorials

Comment: Yea but its worth it, but it takes some time to understand everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i control clicked dragged every where and now it does auto layout itself